# Call onDraw in a static method for a SurfaceView

Tags: android, canvas, view, drawing, surfaceview

I've a SurfaceView to display the CameraPreview. In my Activity, by a Button, I can set the parameters dinamically and now I want to implement that code to display simply effects.

```
      @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

     if (i==0){
      rectanglePaint = new Paint();
      rectanglePaint.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
      rectanglePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
      canvas.drawPaint(rectanglePaint);
     }

     if (i==1){
       rectanglePaint = new Paint();
       rectanglePaint.setARGB(150, 0, 100, 200);
       rectanglePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
       canvas.drawPaint(rectanglePaint);
     }

     ...
```

The int i changes by the onClick method in the button. If I pause and resume the app the effects are shown because it called the onDraw method but there isn't changes when I click the button and stay in the Activity. So, how can I call the onDraw method to show effects? I've already set setWillNotDraw(false); in my Preview. 
The button calls this method in CameraPreview class:

```
        public static void setC1(View v){
        v.setWillNotDraw(false);
        i = 1;
        v.invalidate();//here I want to call onDraw!
        v.postInvalidate();//I try it
             try{
         Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters(); ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mPreview.postInvalidate() inside your Activity. It calls onDraw method in your preview class.